# Footer not working properly

Tags: html, css, drupal, drupal-7

I am trying to make a footer that stays at the same fixed location at the very bottom of the page. I can not get it to lay flat at the very bottom it keeps displaying about 1/10th of the page up. I am also having difficulty getting it to react to browser size changes. I have included a blank div that should expand to keep the footer matching to the browser size, but I currently can not get this to work properly. Everything else on the page reacts correctly with resizing. I have included my CSS and HTML in these two paste bins, I have also included the images in the Imgur link. https://i.stack.imgur.com/qOPep.jpg 
HTML: http://pastebin.com/raw/BCpvspZQ   CSS: http://pastebin.com/raw/2Se0A5ER

```css
.kale-grain-bowls, .salads,
.burgers-sandwiches, .sides,
.smoothies-milkshake, .kids-real-meals{
 background-position: 0% 0%;
 height: 100px;
 float: left;
 margin:2.5px;
 position: relative;
}
.kale-grain-bowls{
 background-image: url('../images-source/templateFoodMainPage.png');
}
.salads{
 background-image: url('../images-source/templateFoodMainPage.png');
 bottom: 72px;
}
.burgers-sandwiches{
 background-image: url('../images-source/templateFoodMainPage.png');
 bottom: 144px;
}
.sides{
 background-image: url('../images-source/templateFoodMainPage.png');
 bottom: 216px;
}
.smoothies-milkshake{
 background-image: url('../images-source/templateFoodMainPage.png');
 bottom: 288px;
}
.kids-real-meals{
 background-image: url('../images-source/templateFoodMainPage.png');
 bottom: 360px;
}
.page{
 height: 100%;
 width: 100%;
 text-align: center;
}
.video, .front-promo-1,
.front-promo-2, .events,
.family-foundation, .partners,
.fundraisers, .cousins, .geniuses,
.greats, .vision{
 margin: 2.5px;
 float: left;
 position: relative;
}
.video{
 height: 300px;
 background-image: url('../images-source/videoImage.png');
 bottom: 360px;
}
.front-promo-1{
 height: 147.5px;
 background-image: url('../images-source/templateMainpage.png');
 bottom: 360px;
}
.front-promo-2{
 height: 147.5px;
 background-image: url('../images-source/templateMainpage.png');
 bottom: 360px;
}
.events{
 height: 300px;
 background-image: url('../images-source/communitySlideshow.png');
}
.family-foundation{
 height: 149px;
 background-image: url('../images-source/Familyfoundation.png');
 bottom: 75px;
}
.partners{
 height: 149px;
 background-image: url('../images-source/Familyfoundation.png');
 bottom: 75px;
}
.fundraisers{
 height: 149px;
 background-image: url('../images-source/Familyfoundation.png');
 bottom: 125px;
}
.cousins{
 height: 149px;
 background-image: url('../images-source/communitybottom.png');
 bottom: 72px;
}
.geniuses{
 height: 149px;
 background-image: url('../images-source/communitybottom.png');
 bottom: 72px;
}
.greats{
 height: 149px;
 background-image: url('../images-source/communitybottom.png');
 bottom: 72px;
}
.vision{
 height: 300px;
 background-image: url('../images-source/about.png');
}
.location-data{
 float:left;
 width:50%;
 height:100%;
}
.location-image{
 float: left;
 background-image: url('../images-source/communitybottom.png');
 height: 300px
}
.location-text{
 float: left;
 bottom: 1px;
}
.foodblock{
 float: left;
 margin: 10px;
 height: auto;
 bottom: 50px;
}
.textblock{
 float: left;
 margin: 20px;
 text-align: center;
}
.foodcontent{
 bottom: 500px;
}
.menu-type{
 text-align: center;
 font-weight: bold;
 font-family: "Times New Roman", Georgia, Serif;
 font-size: 2.5em;
}
.spicy-avocado-lime, .toasted-almond-ginger,
.power-bowl, .farmstand-tomato-basil,
.chicken-caesar, .harvest-kale,
.southwestern-chicken, .watermelon-feta,
.summer-berry-salad, .cousin-oliver,
.west-side, .el-guapo, .adopted-luke,
.buffalo, .elizel, .real-fries,
.sweet-potato-fries, .crisp-veggies,
.side-salad, .seasonal-special,
.kale-crush, .acai-berry,
.strawberry-banana, .lucy-blue,
.seasonal-special-smoothie,
.vanilla, .chocolate, 
.kids-burger, .grilled-cheese,
.hot-dog, .kids-smoothie, .local-apple-bacon-bowl{
 height: 200px;
 float: left;
 width: 100%;
}
.spicy-avocado-lime{
 background-image: url('../images-source/communitybottom.png');
}
.toasted-almond-ginger{
 background-image: url('../images-source/communitybottom.png');
}
.local-apple-bacon-bowl{
 background-image: url('../images-source/communitybottom.png');
}
.power-bowl{
 background-image: url('../images-source/communitybottom.png');
}
.farmstand-tomato-basil{
 background-image: url('../images-source/communitybottom.png');
}
.chicken-caesar{
 background-image: url('../images-source/communitybottom.png');
}
.harvest-kale{
 background-image: url('../images-source/communitybottom.png');
}
.southwestern-chicken{
 background-image: url('../images-source/communitybottom.png');
}
.watermelon-feta{
 background-image: url('../images-source/communitybottom.png');
}
.summer-berry-salad{
 background-image: url('../images-source/communitybottom.png');
}
.salad-subtext{
 width: 100%;
 text-align: center;
}
.cousin-oliver{
 background-image: url('../images-source/communitybottom.png');
}
.west-side{
 background-image: url('../images-source/communitybottom.png');
}
.el-guapo{
 background-image: url('../images-source/communitybottom.png');
}
.adopted-luke{
 background-image: url('../images-source/communitybottom.png');
}
.buffalo{
 background-image: url('../images-source/communitybottom.png');
}
.elizel{
 background-image: url('../images-source/communitybottom.png');
}
.burger-top-text{
 text-align: center;
 width: 100%;
}
.burger-bottom-text{
 text-align: center;
 width: 100%;
}
.real-fries{
 background-image: url('../images-source/communitybottom.png');
}
.sweet-potato-fries{
 background-image: url('../images-source/communitybottom.png');
}
.crisp-veggies{
 background-image: url('../images-source/communitybottom.png');
}
.side-salad{
 background-image: url('../images-source/communitybottom.png');
}
.seasonal-special{
 background-image: url('../images-source/communitybottom.png');
}
.kale-crush{
 background-image: url('../images-source/communitybottom.png');
}
.acai-berry{
 background-image: url('../images-source/communitybottom.png');
}
.strawberry-banana{
 background-image: url('../images-source/communitybottom.png');
}
.lucy-blue{
 background-image: url('../images-source/communitybottom.png');
}
.seasonal-special-smoothie{
 background-image: url('../images-source/communitybottom.png');
}
.vanilla{
 background-image: url('../images-source/communitybottom.png');
}
.chocolate{
 background-image: url('../images-source/communitybottom.png');
}
.smoothies-top-text{
 width: 100%;
}
.milkshakes-text{
 width: 100%;
 text-align: center;
}
.kids-burger{
 background-image: url('../images-source/communitybottom.png');
}
.grilled-cheese{
 background-image: url('../images-source/communitybottom.png');
}
.hot-dog{
 background-image: url('../images-source/communitybottom.png');
}
.kids-smoothie{
 background-image: url('../images-source/communitybottom.png');
}
.kids-real-meal-text{
 width: 100%;
}
.clear-div{
 clear: both;
}
.bgood-footer{
 width:100%;
 height: 20%;
 position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.mobile-app, .talk,
.careers, .press,
.blank, .fb, .yt
.tw, .ig, .orderng-loc{
 float: left;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
.mobile-app{
 background-image: url('../images-source/mobile-app-button.png');
 width: 10%;
}
.talk{
 background-image: url('../images-source/talk-to-us.png');
 width: 10%;
}
.careers{
 background-image: url('../images-source/careers.png');
 width: 10%;
}
.press{
 background-image: url('../images-source/press.png');
 width: 10%;
}
.blank{
 background-image: url('../images-source/blank.png');
 width: 10%;
}
.fb{
 background-image: url('../images-source/fb.png');
 width: 5%;
}
.yt{
 background-image: url('../images-source/yt.png');
 width: 5%;
}
.tw{
 background-image: url('../images-source/tw.png');
 width: 5%;
}
.ig{
 background-image: url('../images-source/ig.png');
 width: 5%;
}
.ordering-loc{
 background-image: url('../images-source/ordering-loc.png');
 width: 10%;
}
.clearfix:after {
     visibility: hidden;
     display: block;
     font-size: 0;
     content: " ";
     clear: both;
     height: 0;
     }
.clearfix { display: inline-block; }
/* start commented backslash hack \*/
* html .clearfix { height: 1%; }
.clearfix { display: block; }
/* close commented backslash hack */

img.footer-img{
  width:50px;
}
img.mobile-app-img{
 width: 150px;
 height: 100%;
}
img.talk-to-us-img{
 width: 150px;
 height: 100%;
}
img.careers-img{
 width: 100px;
 height: 100%;
}
img.press-img{
 width: 100px;
 height: 100%;
}
img.ordering-loc-img{
 width: 190px;
 height: 100%;
}
ul.clearfix{
  list-style:none;
  margin:2px;
  padding:2px 2px;
  width:100%;
  float:left;
}

li.foot{
  float:left;
  height: 45px;
}

li.left {
  float:left;
}

li.mid{
  float:left;
}

li.right{
  float:left;
}
/*for mobile phones: */
 [class*="col-"]{
  width:100%;
 }

@media only screen and (min-width: 600px) {
    /* For tablets: */
    .col-m-1 {width: 8%;}
    .col-m-2 {width: 16%;}
    .col-m-2-5 {width: 21.55%;}
    .col-m-3 {width: 28%;}
    .col-m-4 {width: 32.5%;}
    .col-m-5 {width: 40%;}
    .col-m-6 {width: 48%;}
    .col-m-7 {width: 56%;}
    .col-m-8 {width: 65.7%;}
    .col-m-9 {width: 72%;}
    .col-m-10 {width: 80%;}
    .col-m-11 {width: 88%;}
    .col-m-12 {width: 96%;}
    /*footer data: */
    .foot-m-0{width:0%;}
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px){
 /*for mobile desktop: */
 .col-1 {width: 8%;}
 .col-2-5 {width: 21.55%;}
    .col-2 {width: 16%;}
    .col-3 {width: 28%;}
    .col-4 {width: 32.5%;}
    .col-5 {width: 40%;}
    .col-6 {width: 48%;}
    .col-7 {width: 56%;}
    .col-8 {width: 65.7%;}
    .col-9 {width: 72%;}
    .col-10 {width: 80%;}
    .col-11 {width: 88%;}
    .col-12 {width: 96%;}
    /*footer data: */
    .foot-m-0{width:0%;}
}
```

```html
<div class="page">
<a href="/menu/kale-grain-bowls"><div class="col-m-2 col-2 kale-grain-bowls">Kale & Grain Bowls</div></a>
<a href="/menu/salads"><div class="col-m-2 col-2 salads">Salads</div></a>
<a href="/menu/burgers-sandwiches"><div class="col-m-2 col-2 burgers-sandwiches">Burgers & Sandwiches</div></a>
<a href="/menu/sides"><div class="col-m-2 col-2 sides">Sides</div></a>
<a href="/menu/smoothies-shakes"><div class="col-m-2 col-2 smoothies-milkshake">Smoothies & Milkshakes</div></a>
<a href="/menu/kids-real-meals"><div class="col-m-2 col-2 kids-real-meals">Kid's Real Meals</div></a>
<div class="col-m-8 col-8 video">Video</div>
<a href="/promo/temp1"><div class="col-m-4 col-4  front-promo-1">Promo one</div></a>
<a href="/promo/temp2"><div class="col-m-4 col-4 front-promo-2">Promo two</div></a>
<div class="bgood-footer clearfix">
<ul class= clearfix>
 <li class="left foot"><a href="/mobile-app"><img src="/sites/acquia-drupal-7-50-52-6330.dd/files/mobile-app-button.png" class ="mobile-app-img"></a></li>
 <li class="left foot"><a href=""><img src="/sites/acquia-drupal-7-50-52-6330.dd/files/talk-to-us.png" class ="talk-to-us-img"></a></li>
 <li class="left foot"><a href=""><img src="/sites/acquia-drupal-7-50-52-6330.dd/files/careers.png" class ="careers-img"></a></li>
 <li class="left foot"><a href=""><img src="/sites/acquia-drupal-7-50-52-6330.dd/files/press.png" class ="press-img"></a></li>
        <li class = "mid foot foot-m-0"></li>
 <li class="foot"><a href=""><img src="/sites/acquia-drupal-7-50-52-6330.dd/files/fb.png" class ="footer-img"></a></li>
 <li class="foot"><a href=""><img src="/sites/acquia-drupal-7-50-52-6330.dd/files/yt.png" class ="footer-img"></a></li>
 <li class="foot"><a href=""><img src="/sites/acquia-drupal-7-50-52-6330.dd/files/tw.png" class ="footer-img"></a></li>
 <li class="foot"><a href=""><img src="/sites/acquia-drupal-7-50-52-6330.dd/files/ig.png" class ="footer-img"></a></li>
 <li class="right foot"><a href=""><img src="/sites/acquia-drupal-7-50-52-6330.dd/files/ordering-loc.png" class ="ordering-loc-img"></a></li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: In .bgood-footer you have height set to 20%. Change that to a fixed value (e.g. 100px) to get your footer to stay in place.

Comment: Positioning is a **very** poor method of laying out webpages. It is extremely inflexible and there are much better and more responsive options. Check out [**LearnLayout.com**](http://learnlayout.com/)

Comment: removing height has solved the height issue thank you. I still can not get it to expand with the page properly but I will start reading the learnlayout.com information

Comment: @P.Burden To be honest, your code looks like a mess so far. Paulie_D's resource has some very useful information. I'd recommend you take some time and look into responsive frameworks such as Bootstrap or Foundation.

Comment: Sorry, I haven't built a site in a few years and was taught to use positioning and div's and to avoid spans, I am reading up on Paulie_D's resource now. Also, I am not allowed to use those frameworks on this project since this is a Drupal site powered by another company who is supposed to have a framework that I am using but in reality, they don't have that functionality.

Comment: Thank you for the link I know realize I need to not use the fixed position. Is it possible for someone to help me get it to display below the div's that are already on the page? I have done Tim Troiano's fix but now it is stuck to the bottom of the page even though I have removed all calls to bottom and clear that I can find

Comment: Having read the website I am not sure what you mean by positioning is a poor choice considering it teaches positioning until it teaches about in-line which doesn't work on IE 6 and IE 7. That is the issue I need this to work on as many browsers as possible and IE 7 is listed as one of the mandatory ones. So I don't see how it is poor when the other option does not even work for the browsers I need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I'm understanding the question correctly and you have a fixed height footer then you can use a min-height on your main to push it to the bottom of the page using *calc()*.

So for example you have a HTML layout like:

```
<body>
  <main><!-- Some Content --></main>
  <footer><!-- Footer Content --></footer>
<body>
```

Then your css would be something like:

```
.footer {
  height: 200px;
}

.main {
  min-height: calc(100vh - 200px);
}
```

As far as I'm aware *calc()* is a widely supported function on modern browsers both mobile and desktop. The viewport height unit *vh* is also fairly widely supported.

You'd have to recalculate for various media queries to make it truly responsive.

Alternatively, if you don't know the footer height you can calculate it on the fly with jQuery(or vanilla js if you're familiar with it) to add a minimum height:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  var height = window.innerHeight;
  var footerHeight = $('footer').outerHeight();
  $('main').css('min-height', (height - footerHeight) + 'px');
});
```

I'm sure some of the experts on SO will have more answers for you but that's my take on it.

Comment: Completely missed the pastebins. My bad people, don't punish me. I agree completely with Paulie_D. Positioning is no way to layout a page

Comment: I'm reading up on it now. I was taught not to use spans but instead div's and positioning. I am just following schematics left for me. That doesn't mean I think the layout is perfectly the way it should be. Having read more about the positioning issue, do you possibly know how I can get it to be sitting underneath the other div's then? Cause currently now I have it stuck to the bottom despite removing all calls to bottom and clear that I can find.

Comment: It sounds like you're learning some bad habits and perhaps lack a good foundational understanding. I recommend free code camp, you'll go far with HTML quickly there :)

Comment: Thank you, this is my first HTML site in 4 years, so I am definitely rusty. I finished reading Paulie_D's link and it still supports the reason I was told to build it out this way since what everyone else has suggested does not work on older browsers which I have been told I must have it compatible with. The more I keep investigating it seems to me like my problem has too many constraints that everyone seems to ignore because it is simpler that way, or I am misunderstanding when these resources people suggest tell me that there are incompatibilities with these methods and my constraints

Comment: Being backwards compatible is great and definitely advised, however, gone are days of supporting IE8 in my view, so I guess that's why people aren't trying to understand. A helpful resource in finding out what you can and can't use for each individual browser is [link](http://caniuse.com/) and visit [link](http://caniuse.com/usage-table) to see who's using what browser and you'll see that it's very rare for people to use outdated browsers

Comment: Thank you for your help, I'm just trying to build to the schematics I was given even though they don't really match to reality or practicality from a programming perspective at all. Thank you!